# Sequelize: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

i'm using nestjs/sequelize/postgres
i initiated my db and passed it as provider to my database module,i explicitly supplied dialect and used

> NODE_ENV= development

in my .env file,but i still get the same error

```
dotenv.config();
export const databaseProviders = [{
provide: "SEQUELIZE",
useFactory: async () => {
    let config;
    switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case development:
       config = databaseConfig.development;
       break;
    case TEST:
       config = databaseConfig.test;
       break;
    case PRODUCTION:
       config = databaseConfig.production;
       break;
    default:
       config = databaseConfig.development;
    }
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(config);
    sequelize.addModels([foo,bar]);
    await sequelize.sync();
    return sequelize;
},
}];
```

and i'm reading my configs from .env file :

```
export const databaseConfig: IDatabaseConfig = {
    development: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME_DEVELOPMENT,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    },
    test: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME_TEST,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    },
    production: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME_PRODUCTION,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    },
};
```

.env file :

```
NODE_ENV= development

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=user
DB_PASS=pass
DB_DIALECT=postgres
DB_NAME_TEST=test_database_name
DB_NAME_DEVELOPMENT=development_database_name
DB_NAME_PRODUCTION=production_database_name
```

Comment: Did you check `config` right before `new Sequelize`?

Comment: @Anatoly
i set a breakpoint there,this is my config object:
{
  username: "foo",
  password: "bar",
  database: "baz",
  host: "localhost",
  port: "5432",
  dialect: "postgres",
}

Comment: Just to be clear: you do have `pg` package installed, don't you?

Comment: @Anatoly yes i have

Comment: Did you try the same config (just like a static object) in a separate project only with `Sequelize` and `pg` installed?